# Is there a way to display folded parts as a tree?

Tags: folding

Folding is useful to hide away parts of the document. A visual representation of the folding structure as a tree would be useful for understanding the document structure at a glance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `:set foldcolumn=<number>` to display a `<number>`-wide column that tries to visualize fold levels. It would look something like this, by default (with a marker fold method, using `{{{` and `}}}`):

```
-    {{{ Top Level Fold
|-   {{{ Nested Fold
||-  {{{ Deepest Fold
|||  }}}
||   }}}
|-   {{{ Another Nested Fold
||   }}}
|    }}}
```

However, this consumes quite a lot of horizontal real-estate. Another method would be to write a custom `foldtext()` implementation which reads the fold level with `foldlevel()` and formats accordingly. This will waste less horizontal space, but won't really be as helpful for visually understanding the tree since you can't see the folds underneath a collapsed fold. For example, your `.vimrc`:

```
set foldtext=CustomFoldText()
function! CustomFoldText()
  let line = getline(v:foldstart) . "..."
  return repeat("--| ", v:foldlevel) . line
endfunction
```

There are plugins that provide on-demand visualizations of the fold hierarchy, such as [folddigest.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=732), as well. They work, essentially, by parsing the fold level of every line, building up an appropriate data structure, and dumping a visualization of the data structure to a new buffer. You could probably adapt the technique to your own needs.

You may also want to look at plugins that provide "indent guides," such as [this one](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides). I've never personally used them, and I hear they cause some people performance issues since they generally involve generating lots of custom match highlights via `matchadd()`, but your mileage may vary.